# How to round up an number to a multiple of another number?

Tags: c++, algorithm, modulo, integer-division

I'm trying to design a function `int smallestDivisibleAfter(int number, int divisor)` such that it returns the smallest number greater than or equal to `number` that is divisible by `divisor` (which is non-zero) . Here all inputs and outputs are assumed to be non-negative.

Examples:

```
smallestDivisibleAfter(9,4); // Returns 12
smallestDivisibleAfter(16,2); // Returns 16
```

I came up with the code `number + divisor - number % divisor`. However this ceases to work when `number % divisor == 0`, since then `smallestDivisibleAfter(16,2); // Returns 18` instead of `16`.

In addition, `number - 1 + divisor - (number - 1)% divisor` does not work since `int` will be replaced by `unsigned long long` when I put this code into action.

What is the best solution here?

Comment: `divisor * ((number / divisor) + (number % divisor ? 1 : 0))`?

Comment: `(number + divisor - 1) / divisor * divisor` ?

Comment: Your question is inconsistent with your example -- 18 is the "smallest number greater than 16 that is divisible by 2", and 16 isn't.

Comment: @PaulHankin Here greater is interpreted as `>=`

Comment: AlexD's seems to be the simplest method.

Comment: I will edit your post to change the wording to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: `((number - 1) / divisor + 1) * divisor` is also a possibility.

Comment: @m69 No, it's not, because `number` will be an unsigned int and `number - 1` will result in an underflow.

Comment: @JuanLopes You're right, I forgot about the "unsigned long long" part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid jumps, try:

```
number - number % divisor + divisor * !!(number % divisor)
```

The `!!x` just converts the number to a boolean with 0 if `x==0` and 1 otherwise.

Comment: Are you sure at the assembly level that `!!` can do that without a branch?

Comment: @MarkB If we're talking about x86, this would be a simple setnz. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Ah not at all, I'm just not that fluent with x86 assembly.

Answer (score -2):

```
((number / divisor)  + 1) * divisor)
```

This will return the next greatest multiple of divisor after number.

If you ever plan on using floats:
 `floor(number / divisor)`.

Comment: Integer division doesn't result in a float; there's nothing to floor().

Comment: A small suggestion: it's better to gain confidence in your answer before publishing it. The goal of answering isn't to guess the right answer as quickly as possible, it's to provide a correct and convincing answer that other people can read and understand.

Comment: Yeah I just edited that, originally I didn't bother with floor then added it in casehe decides to use floats

Comment: This is not correct because if `number` is already divisible by `divisor` it will return `number + divisor`.